# Continuity of $\lim_{t\to +\infty} f(tx)/t$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f\in \mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R})$ such that
$$\exists k >0,\forall x\in \mathbb{R}^n,\qquad |f(x)|\le k(1+\left\| x \right\|) 
$$
and 
$$\forall x\in \mathbb{R}^n,\qquad f_{\infty}(x)=\lim_{t\to + \infty} \frac{f(tx)}{t} \text{exists}.$$

Then, is the function $f_{\infty}$ continuous ? ($f_{\infty}$ is positively homogeneous but does it help...)

Comment: I don't have a good answer. I can only remark that $f_\infty$ is a cone, i.e. $f_\infty (0)= 0$ and $f_\infty(cx) = cf_\infty (x)$ for $c>0$. Is that gonna be useful?

Comment: Yes I already know that $f_{\infty}$ is positively homogeneous but I don't know if it is useful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a counterexample: in dimension $2$, let
$$
f(u,v)=\frac{uv}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}.
$$
Then, $f$ is smooth and $|f(u,v)|\leqslant|v|\leqslant\sqrt{u^2+v^2}$ hence the domination condition holds with $k=1$. For every positive $t$,
$$
\frac{f(tu,tv)}t=\frac{uv}{\sqrt{t^{-2}+u^2}},
$$
hence $f_\infty$ exists and is defined by 
$$
f_\infty(u,v)=s(u)v,
$$
where $s(u)=1$ if $u\gt0$, $s(0)=0$, and $s(u)=-1$ if $u\lt0$.

Thus, $f_\infty$ is continuous on the left halfplane $[u\gt0]$, on the right halfplane $[u\lt0]$ and at $(0,0)$, and discontinuous on the two halflines $[u=0,v\ne0]$.

Comment: Thank you, actually I saw this claim ($f_\infty$ is continuous) in a paper...

Comment: Which paper? $ $

Comment: Demengel, F.; Temam, R. Convex functions of a measure and applications. Indiana Univ. Math. J. 33 (1984), no. 5, 673–709 (the claim is on page 675)

Comment: Right. Maybe they forgot to add the hypothesis that $f$ is convex (later on in the paper, this seems to be mainly the case when $f_\infty$ is used). Dunno if $f$ being convex implies that the asymptote function $f_\infty$ is continuous, though... ([D&T's paper](http://www.iumj.indiana.edu/IUMJ/FTDLOAD/1984/33/33036/pdf).)

Comment: If $f$ is convex, then $f_{\infty}$ is also convex and then since we're talking about convex functions from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$ : $f_{\infty}$ is continuous.